# Pandas column contents as index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set a new pandas column using an existing pandas columns as set of indices to separate list, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series
```

See code below:

```
import pandas as pd

monthvalues=[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144]

df=pd.DataFrame([1,4,7,9], columns=['month'])

df['value']=monthvalues[df['month']-1]
```

Expected result

```
    "month" "value"
0   1       1
1   4       16
2   7       49
3   9       81
```

Note that this is just an example, I'm not actually trying to square the month digit in reality.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `df['month']` returns a Pandas Series, not a list as I suspect you expect (although it still wouldn't work if it were a list).

I'm not sure if there's a neater way, but try this:

```
df['value'] = [monthvalues[x] for x in df['month']-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a `Series` from the list you can pass this as a lookup using `iloc` and importantly convert the `Series` to a numpy array so it aligns correctly:

```
In [41]:
monthvalues=[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144]
df=pd.DataFrame([1,4,7,9], columns=['month'])
df['value']=pd.Series(monthvalues).iloc[df['month']-1].values
df

Out[41]:
   month  value
0      1      1
1      4     16
2      7     49
3      9     81
```